# OpenShift 4.3 - Attach PVC to pod without privileged access

Tags: openshift

I'm trying to mount PVC to MongoDB deployment without privileged access.
I've tried to set `anyuid` for pods via:

```
oc adm policy add-scc-to-user anyuid -z default --as system:admin
```

In deployment I'm using `securityContext` config. I've tried several combination of `fsGroup` etc. :

```
spec:
      securityContext:
        runAsUser: 99
        runAsGroup: 99
        supplementalGroups:
          - 99
        fsGroup: 99
```

When I go to the pod uid and guid is set correctly:

```
bash-4.2$ id
uid=99(nobody) gid=99(nobody) groups=99(nobody)
bash-4.2$ whoami
nobody
bash-4.2$ cd /var/lib/mongodb/data
bash-4.2$ touch test.txt
touch: cannot touch 'test.txt': Permission denied
```

But pod can't write to the pvc directory:

```
ERROR: Couldn't write into /var/lib/mongodb/data
CAUSE: current user doesn't have permissions for writing to /var/lib/mongodb/data directory
DETAILS: current user id = 99, user groups: 99 0
DETAILS: directory permissions: drwxr-xr-x owned by 0:0, SELinux: system_u:object_r:container_file_t:s0:c234,c491
```

I've tried to instantiate also MySQL template with PVC without any configuration change from OpenShift catalog and it's the same issue.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Temporary solution is to use init container with root privileges to change owner of mounted path:

```
initContainers:
    - name: mongodb-init
      image: alpine
      command: ["sh", "-c", "chown -R 99 /var/lib/mongodb/data"]
      volumeMounts:
      - mountPath: /var/lib/mongodb/data
        name: mongodb-pvc
```

But also I'm looking at tool named Udica. It can generate SELinux security policies for container: https://github.com/containers/udica